# grails + gwt request handling via controllers

Tags: gwt, grails, request, controllers

I am new to gwt. I am trying to integrate gwt+grails.Can anybody provide me a good example for handling the request using grails controllers and not a custom servlet.I will be really thankful if anybody can guide me :)

Answer (score 1):

I had some success by returning json from grails controllers. [Look here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GRAILS/Converters+Reference) for more info. Then, on the gwt client side, create javascript "overlay" types, and then use RequestBuilder to make a request to the grails controller to retrieve json. [Here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tutorials/1.6/JSON.html) is a good tutorial, but you can skip the section that describes how to create a servlet to return json, because your grails controllers will do that.